# I am getting error when i am trying to convert HTML to PDF, How can I resolve this?

Tags: javascript, html-to-pdf

I convert html data from response to pdf but got the error...my code is

```js
this.httpClient.post("/getreport/1", obj, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).subscribe((data) => {
var dd=new Uint8Array(data)
        var file = new Blob([dd], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        filename = this.report.key + ".pdf";



 let $link = document.createElement("a");
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    $link.setAttribute("href", url);
    $link.setAttribute("download", filename);
    $link.style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild($link);
    $link.click();

});
```

**ERROR: FAILED TO LOAD PDF**

Comment: Your final `)}` seem to be the wrong way around, though that sounds like an issue with the example rather than the actual code given the error message.

Comment: sorry code is fine ,i copied here it wrong...but error is same

Comment: I don't think that you can convert html to pdf using `new Blob...`. It might be better if your `/getreport/1` returns pdf.